# Manually attach one instance of SQL Server database from another SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, database, instances

I have installed two SQL Server instances, one is SQL Server 2012 and the other is SQL Server 2014.

I connected to the SQL Server 2014 instance using Management Studio and clicked "Attach", while clicking add "Locate Database Files" window is opened and I am not able to see the SQL Server 2012 instance databases.

Is it possible to attach other instance's databases without moving databases to another location?

Answer (score 1):

Is the database you are trying to attach still being used by the 2012 instance? A database cannot be attached to two instances simultaneously. As long as SQL Server can see a drive (or a share) it can attach a database to it (as long as the database being attached is the same or lower version.)

Comment: Ya I detached 2012 database after that also  i cannot attach.The 2012 instance of "DATA" folder  cannot expanded in management studio .

Comment: It sounds like the user you are running under in 2014 does not have the necessary permissions on the 2012 data folder.

Comment: Ya that's correct.There is any way to grant permission to 2012 data folder?.

Comment: Not from within SQL Server. You, or the owner of the folder, at the file system level (Windows/DOS/Windows Explorer...) has to grant read/write permission on the folder ,or files (mdf/ndf/ldf), to the SQL Server 2014 ( target) sysadmin user.

Comment: ya ok.Thank you .I will check with that.

Comment: I also give the permission ..Stil the databases are not listed in the data folder...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a Linked Server?
See e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Comment: ya i tried linked server .But after that also the databases are not listed.